# How to extract Pandas dataframe from a PostgreSQL *.sql file?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I have a `*.sql` file from which I need to extract data.
I could read the `pandas` dataframe using `sqlite3` package. However, I'm now sure how to do that with PostgreSQL file. I have looked into [this](https://gist.github.com/jakebrinkmann/de7fd185efe9a1f459946cf72def057e), but it seems it requires a connection to some database in the backend. I'm not sure how to do it for an `*.sql` dump.

I tried the following code, but I get an error:

```
import psycopg2

conn= psycopg2.connect(dbname='pagila-data.sql')
```

error:

```
OperationalError: FATAL:  role "****" does not exist
```

Where **** is the username of the profile in the machine.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ```psycopg2``` is for connecting to a database not a file.  Without knowing the content and format of  ```pagila-data.sql```  an answer to this question is not going to happen.

Comment: Hi, the data is from here: https://github.com/devrimgunduz/pagila/blob/master/pagila-data.sql

Comment: So either you have to build a parser to walk over that file or download the complete pagila dump and restore it into a database. Then you could use psycopg2 to pull the data out of the the database.